# How can I copy another buttons style?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `TextField` widget with the labelText "Description".

I'm trying to make this TextField have the same style as a `FlatButton` widget

I was reading about using `copyWith` but I don't fully understand how to use it.

I was also looking at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/flat_button.dart but I don't really think this explains much

```
return TextField(
  style: TextStyle(),
  onChanged: _bloc.changeEventDescription,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Description", border: InputBorder.none),
);
```

Setting `border: InputBorder.none` at least got rid of the line underneath the `FlatButton`

The dream is for `TextField` to look like a default `FlatButton`

Thanks!!

Comment: hmm add some pictures about what you need.  Theme is an inheritedWidget so you can access from any widget using Theme.of(context).

Comment: @diegoveloper How do I grab the font color and style and size of a default flat button using this?

Comment: both are different type of widgets but you can try to build a custom flatbutton, could you add a picture about what you need?

Comment: I see, but i would want the flatbutton to have a textfield when clicked on. I'm not sure about how to go about showing a picture of what I want, it would literally look like a flatbutton when not clicked

Comment: You can customize the flatbutton , so we don't know what type of design you would like

Comment: @diegoveloper "The dream is for TextField to look like a FlatButton". Why do you think I want to customize the flatbutton?

Comment: Why don't you use FlatButton (child: TextField) ? Also FlatButton UI depends of the Theme of you have on your app, so ....

Comment: @diegoveloper lmao. Because I want the field to expand when I click on it, which I don't think I can make flatbutton do. I edited the question to say default flatbutton so that it's easier to understand.

Comment: well , you have the source code of FlatButton , it uses the RawMaterialButton , so build your own widget based on the style you want :).

Comment: @diegoveloper Right. So as the question asks, how do I go about grabbing the style and color off of a FlatButton...? How do I build my own widget with that specific style?

Comment: check this video  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1pNjxmNHNQ

Comment: @diegoveloper Just watched the video. I don't see anywhere about calling specific settings from a different widget?

Comment: Now read this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `FlatButton` and create a custom widget (just like `FlatButton` extends `MaterialButton`). So your class will look something like this -

```
class myButton extends FlatButton {}
```

You can override child to `TextFormField`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. How would I go about using this to actually create a TextField that looks like a FlatButton though?

Comment: Tell me something, Why don't you just do this? `FlatButton(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          onPressed: () {
            print('pressed');
          },
          child: TextField(
            decoration: null,
          ),
        )` (You can add the decoration if you want)

Comment: I guess my question is, what is the default font size, and font of a FlatButton?

Comment: That is same as `RawMaterialButton` and you can use `ButtonTheme` for that. Notice this code in `FlatButton` - `highlightColor: buttonTheme.getHighlightColor(this),
      splashColor: buttonTheme.getSplashColor(this),
      elevation: buttonTheme.getElevation(this),
      highlightElevation: buttonTheme.getHighlightElevation(this),
      disabledElevation: buttonTheme.getDisabledElevation(this),
      padding: buttonTheme.getPadding(this)`